# Format a NSMutableArray object to a string

Tags: ios, objective-c

`array` is a `NSMutableArray`. I am adding some string objects to it.

```
[array addObject:@"MM-19"];
[array addObject:@"MM-49"]; 
[array addObject:@"MM-165"];  
[array addObject:@"MM-163"];
```

Now, I need to write a method that will return me a `NSString` in the following format :

`19-49-165-163`

How can this be done ?

Comment: Please replace "MM-" from "-".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your solution,

```
NSString *dashSeperatedString = [array componentsJoinedByString:@"-"] ;
dashSeperatedString = [dashSeperatedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"MM-" withString:@""] ;

NSLog(@"Output : %@", dashSeperatedString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative could be:

```
NSString *combinedStuff = [array componentsJoinedByString:@""];
combinedStuff = [combinedStuff stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"MM" withString:@""];

if ([combinedStuff hasPrefix:@"-"]) 
{
    combinedStuff = [combinedStuff substringFromIndex:1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code will help,

```
NSString *finalString = @"" ;

for (NSString *strvalue in array)
{
    NSArray *temp= [strvalue componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    if ([strvalue isEqualToString:array.lastObject])
    {
        finalString= [finalString stringByAppendingString:temp.lastObject];
    }
    else
    {
        finalString= [finalString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-",temp.lastObject]];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@",finalString);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 2.0:**

```
let mutableArray = NSMutableArray()

  mutableArray.addObject("MM-19")
  mutableArray.addObject("MM-49")
  mutableArray.addObject("MM-165")
  mutableArray.addObject("MM-163")

  var finalString = String()
  finalString = ""

  for stringValue in mutableArray {

   let temp: [AnyObject] = stringValue.componentsSeparatedByString("-")
   finalString = finalString.stringByAppendingString(String(temp.last)+"-")

  }
  print("Final String: \(finalString)")


OR

  var finalSeperatedString: String = mutableArray.componentsJoinedByString("-")
  finalSeperatedString = finalSeperatedString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("MM-", withString: "")
  print("Output String: \(finalSeperatedString)")
```

}